# How to account for capital improvements made on owned property done by owner

Tags: real-estate, capital-gain

As a homeowner one can step up the basis of their home by using the cost of work done by contractors. But I'm not sure what the rules are around stepping up the basis for any DIY improvements.  Can these be stepped up at their equivalent contractor price? does this require some sort of proof of work completed? Is there a proper way to account for the labor costs of the DIY, etc.

Comment: Tip: Tax questions require a country tag.

Comment: in my jurisdiction (France) work done DIY is not allowed in determining capital improvement - only works for which a verifiable  installers invoice is available is allowed to defray the cost of capital improvement for CGT purposes. I'm certain the same rules would apply elsewhere.